# Uploading a CSV file with foreign key into Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have uploaded two datasets (without foreign keys based on Service and Library models see below), but cannot upload the third which has foreign keys for the two other datasets.

First, I'm uploading them in the shell, by running this code in "python manage.py shell". My foreign key columns are service and library and connecting to service via 'cpt' and library via 'hid'.

These are the parts of the code not working

```
service=Service.objects.get(cpt=row['cpt']), 
library=Library.objects.get(hid=row['hid'])
```

This is the full code:

```
from catalog.models import Service, Library, Price
# not including the intro - price dataset gets pulled in
with open('price.csv') as csvfile:
      reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)                             
      for row in reader:                                                                  
            p = Price(com_desc=row['com_desc'],service=Service.objects.get(cpt=row['cpt']),price_offer=row['price_offer'], comments=row['comments'], library=Library.objects.get[hid='hid'])
            p.save()
```

Here is the error that I get (updated):

```
 site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 399, in get
    self.model._meta.object_name
catalog.models.Service.DoesNotExist: Service matching query does not exist.
```

Here are my models: Service, Library and Price. As I said before, Service and Library are already uploaded, but struggling to upload Price because of the foreign keys.

```
# Service Model
class Service(models.Model):
    serviceid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, help_text='Unique ID for this particular service in database')
    desc_us = models.TextField(blank=True, primary_key = True)
    cpt = models.IntegerField(default= 10000)
    price_std = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, blank=True)

# Library Model
class Library(models.Model):
    hid = models.CharField(max_length = 8, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key=True)
    hopid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, help_text='Unique ID for this particular hospital in database')
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 200, null = True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length = 50, null = True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length = 2, null=True)
    zipcode = models.CharField(max_length = 5, null=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length = 12, null=True)

# Price Model, Foreign Keys are; Service, Library (want to connect these by 'cpt' for service and 'hid' for library)
class Price(models.Model):
  priceid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, help_text='Unique ID for this particular service in database')
  com_desc = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank = True, null = True)
  service = models.ForeignKey("Service", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
  price_offer = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, blank=True)
  comments = models.CharField(max_length = 200, blank = True, null =True)
  library = models.ForeignKey("Library", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
```

Sample rows from price.csv

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is clearly too condensed for debugging; try breaking it up:

```
p = Price(com_desc=row['com_desc'],service=Service.objects.get(row['cpt']),price_offer=row['price_offer'], comments=row['comments'], library=Library.objects.get['hid'])
```

One thing that stands out is that you probably mean this:

```
library=Library.objects.get(row['hid'])  # rather than .get['hid']
```

Other than that, I'd create and print out the individual fields separately to make sure they contain what you expect, before creating and trying to save the new `Price` object.

========

If there really is always one and only one `Service` per `cpt` and only one `Library` per `hid`, then using `get()` is fine. You should however formalize that by adding a [unique constraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#unique) to the relevant model fields (if you get an error on adding the constraint, then the values are not unique after all).

If it doesn't matter which one you select when there are several, you can use this:

```
service = Service.objects.filter(row['cpt'])[0]
```

Note that this will throw an error if no records are found for a given `cpt` (but then `get()` would error as well if no matching object is found).

You can do the same with `Library` and `hid`.

Comment: Ths is what is causing the error: service=Service.objects.get(cpt=row['cpt']). Please help me debug this. The rest of the code, not freign keys works.

Comment: What is the content of `row['cpt']` when the error happens? And are you sure there can only be a single `Service` with that `cpt`? There is no unique constraint on `cpt` in your model, and `get()` throws an error (although I'd expect it to be a different one) when more than one object is returned by the query.

Comment: Then `get()` cannot work. You either need a unique identifier in the CSV data to find the one `Service` you want, or if you are content with *any* `Service` that has the correct `cpt`, you need to filter on `cpt` and then select one of potentially several `Service` objects.

Comment: Thanks! Could you show me how to go this. There are multiple prices for every cpt, but only one cpt for every price.

Comment: or at least give me some clues.

Comment: You've described the relationship between price and cpt, but what we need is the relationship between cpt and Service on the one hand, and hid and Library on the other hand. If there is no one-to-one relationship between them, you need to think about how you can select one Service/Library when the criterion you are using returns several of them. If in fact the relationship is one-to-one, see above on how to use filter rather than get.

Comment: cpt is a column in service, but is not the primary key. There are no duplicate cpts in the service table. This is exactly the same for library and hid. It's not a one to one it's many to one with (many prices with the same cpt in the Price table).

Comment: I tried your filter, but get the error - list index out of range

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189402/discussion-between-j-r-and-endre-both).

Comment: I tried your filter, but get the error - list index out of range